# How is the internal id of a WebDriver WebElement computed? Pass multiple elements to JavaScript Executor

Tags: javascript, firefox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to know how the id of a WebElement in WebDriver is internally computed. I need it because i am writing an extension which should boost the performance in cases you need to perform more than one JavaScript command at once.

Example code in Java which retrieves the ID:

```
RemoteWebElement element = driver.findElement(
    By.cssSelector("div#header > img.logo")
);
String id = element.getId();
// id is something like: {390f457d-406b-458a-b4a6-dfebb24aae36}
```

So, i want to pass more than one WebElement to a JavaScript executor, can i achieve it by sending a list of all id's? **I need a possibility to retrieve the DOM element in JavaScript only by knowing these id's.**

I guess the solution is somewhere hidden in the webdriver.xpi implementation. I use the Firefox WebDriver.

**Update**

Ok, let me rephrase my question. Assumed i want to do something with a WebElement in Javascript i can do something like this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("jQuery(arguments[0]).doSomething()", myElement);
```

But how can i pass multiple WebElements (an arbitrary amount) to the script?

Comment: BTW, i did not find the getID in my java WebDriver implementation...

Comment: It is defined in `RemoteWebElement`: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#getId%28%29

Comment: Ahh! Was looking on `WebElement` my bad :)

Comment: you can try do my "for cycle" approach, but it will do one after another. Other approach would be to run multiple threads while testing, but I am not that advanced in Java to actually help you with multithread approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the JavascriptExecutor.ExecuteScript() method will take a collection of WebElements as an argument. There are unit tests in the [JavaScript execution tests](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/ExecutingJavascriptTest.java) for the project that would indicate that's possible. If that's the case, why would the following not work?

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#header > img.logo"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) { jQuery(arguments[0][i]).doSomething(); }", elements);
```

The following example works for me using current sources (Java code):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
String s = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var s=''; for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) { s += arguments[0][i].tagName; } return s;", elements);
driver.quit();
System.out.println(s);
```

I receive "DIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIV..." printed to the console window.

Comment: thanks, this looks promising, but that seems to produce an error (used the object array as shown in `testCanHandleAnArrayOfElementsAsAnObjectArray()`): `Argument is of an illegal type: [Ljava.lang.Object;` In class `WebElementToJsonConverter` you can see that there is no handler for an array of WebElements nor for an array of Objects...

Comment: I've simplified the example somewhat. There isn't any need for the Object array intermediate step. In WebElementToJsonConverter there **is** a handler for Collection<?>, of which List<?> is one. Note that the converter is recursive, so it should convert all of the elements of the list to their JSON representation as well.

Comment: Thanks alot, that helped me. I totally missed that the converter is recursive. I am still struggling with the details, but it seems to work now!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the `findElements()` method rerurns a List of elements. So your code would be more like:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#header > img.logo");
```

and then if you want it pass to some else method why dont you use `for` cycle?:

```
for (WebElement elem : elements){
  doSomethingWithElement(elem);
}
```

the above will go through all elements and use them one by another in a loop.

Another approach would be to wrap the `WebElement` into your custom class - but in that way you have to implement all the abstract methods:

```
public class MyWebElement implements WebElement{
 private int id; // ID of the element which you can define later on
 private WebElement theElement // wrap around this beauty
 // ..
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in my code, i corrected it. It was just an example to show the internal id format of the FireFox WebDriver. I still need a way to access the corresponding element only by knowing this id in JavaScript.

Comment: Ahh! I completly misunderstood what you want to achieve. Going to post another answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if I undrstand it correctly now, you have more images in your DOM. So your HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="header">
 <img class="logo" id="firstID" src="foo.jpg" />
```

Supposing this ID are not that nice and not guessable, so you basically can't do the easiest approach:

```
WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.id("firstID");
```

or pass it to the method by some easy searching. (Like inspect element and then do something like):

```
(JavaScriptExecutor).executeScript(doSomethingWithId("firstID"));
```

Okay. In that way this shoud do the trick:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#header > img.logo"));
String id = element.getAttribute("id");
```

The above should return you `firstID` as String value. I never tried it in my tests, but I hope it will work

Comment: That's still not what i wanted. I am not sure how to express myself correctly so that you can see what i am trying to do. It is a general task, not limited on images. Let's say i have a `findElements()` command which returns a list of `WebElement` objects. I want to put all of the internal id's (i am not speaking of the html id attribute) by calling `getId()` in a list. This list is sent to a JavaScript executor which then needs to retrieve the corresponding elements only by knowing these id's.

Comment: but the WebElement internal ID is not related with real world ID. The WebElement is Java representation of one HTML element in the DOM. JavaScript should do something with real HTML. Why should the Javascript know only the ID? I am quite lost here...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my question, maybe it is more precise now.